# Ubuntu server is sending emails via Gmail. How do I stop this?

Tags: ubuntu, sendmail, ubuntu-12.04, gmail

I have recently taken ownership of a sever which hosts multiple websites.

For some reason, when the websites send notification emails (i.e - when a contact form is submitted) the email received comes from a personal Gmail account.

I am trying to get to the bottom of this, but am having difficulty. How do I find out which email mosdule is installed on my server? How do I stop the emails being routed through the Gamil account? Which is the best email module I need to install to send php emails?

Interestingly, when I SSH into my server I see the following message:

```
No mail.
85.xx.93.xx
The program 'mailx' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install mailutils
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that e-mails really "come from" that gmail account? Check the headers of the e-mail to see where the mail is really coming from.

Answer (score 1):

If the email is being sent when a form is submitted from a web page, then the FROM address is most likely set in the code of the web page.

Begin your investigation in the websites code.

Answer (score 0):

How to detect which email/MTA server is installed?

Check your SMTP server greeting message.

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 25
```